# How to use externel CSS and (static) images in Go, Google App Engine

Tags: css, image, google-app-engine, go

I'm working on a webpage in Go. The Go code uses "html/template" to parse HTML. I would like to use CSS in the project. Everything is working well when I use internal CSS code, but when I would like to change to external it dosen't work. It looks like it can't access to the .css file.

Here is my app.yaml configuration:

```
application: makerboardstest
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images
```

Here is how I would like to access to the .css from the html:

```
<head>
<link href="/stylesheets/main.css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

I also have problems with (static) images. I would like to access to the image with this html code:

```
<img src="/images/img1.jpg" />
```

What can be the problem?

(I'm testing it on my PC, Win 7)

Comment: try <link href="../stylesheets/main.css" media="screen" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handlers are checked in order, and your first handler matches everything; move your static handlers up above it. In other words, when your browser makes a request for `/stylesheets/main.css`, it matches the `/.*` pattern of your first handler and asks go to serve it rather than trying the static dir. If you flip the order of the handlers, it will match `/stylesheets` first and serve it from the static dir.

i.e.:

```
handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images 

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```